# Interesting easy looking Regex

Tags: regex

I am re-phrasing my question to clear confusions!

I want to match if a string has certain letters for this I use the character class:

```
[ACD]
```

and it works perfectly!

but I want to match if the string has those letter(s) 2 or more times either repeated or 2 separate letters

For example:
`[AKL]` should match:

```
ABCVL
AAGHF
KKUI
AKL
```

But the above should not match the following:

```
ABCD
KHID
LOVE
```

because those are there but only once!

that's why I was trying to use:

```
[ACD]{2,}
```

But it's not working, probably it's not the right Regex.. can somebody a Regex guru can help me solve this puzzle?

Thanks

PS: I will use it on MYSQL -  a differnt approach can also welcome! but I like to use regex for smarter and shorter query!

Comment: I thought it was very simple, no?

Comment: Are you saying if you have the string `ABCCA`, you want to return `A` and `C` because they are seen two or more times?

Comment: No, I want to check if my string has 2 or more letters that are listed in the SET!

Comment: So if your set is `[ABC]`, it would not match `A` but it would match `AC`?

Comment: so in my exmaple, regex should match:
ACDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZ

Comment: if my set is [ABC] it should match ABC, if my set is [ALZ] is should match ALZ but not A21 or L32 or 14Z

Comment: similarly if my set is [ALZ] it should not match ABC but ASZ or ALK would be matched because 2 or more letters of SET are available!

Comment: So, I believe I understood you and my answer should help.

Comment: The solution is probably trivial. But if you need distinctly different characters, like 3 distinct out of 5 letters, something like this `(?:.*([ABCDE])(?!.*\1)){3}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ensure that a string contains at least two occurencies in a set of letters (lets say  `A K L` as in your example), you can write something like this:

```
[AKL].*[AKL]
```

Since the MySQL regex engine is a DFA, there is no need to use a negated character class like `[^AKL]` in place of the dot to avoid backtracking, or a lazy quantifier that is not supported at all.

example:

```
SELECT 'KKUI' REGEXP '[AKL].*[AKL]';
```

will return `1`

You can follow [this link](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:538412/FULLTEXT01.pdf) that speaks on the particular subject of the LIKE and the REGEXP features in MySQL.

Comment: Have my +1, even though it's virtually my answer from 2 days ago that OP initially claimed as faulty. But, you gave him his MySQL query as well.

Answer (score 2):

*If* I understood you correctly, this is quite simple:

```
[A-Z].*?[A-Z]
```

This looks for your something in your set, `[A-Z]`, and then lazily matches characters until it (potentially) comes across the set, `[A-Z]`, again.

---

As @Enigmadan pointed out, a lazy match is not necessary here: `[A-Z].*[A-Z]`

Comment: 1) This will also count the letters I want to exclude!
2) I want it to be only matched if 2 or more letters exists in a string

Comment: @mahaidery 1) a regex match has to be consecutive characters, so you can't match `A` and `Z` from `A123Z` (unless you want to do two different matches). 2) this will fail if less than 2 letters from the set exist in the string.

Comment: f I use [ACDFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXZ] it works perfectly, but I want it to only match when the string has 2 or more letters mentioned in the SET or a single letter repeated 2 or more times..

Comment: @mahaidery why doesn't [my first answer work](http://regex101.com/r/zM0nU2/1)? Or do you need it to match the entire string at that point. In that case, what makes up an entire "string"?

Comment: @Sam I don't think you need the question mark. Doesn't `*` already check for zero or more?

Comment: You're right, @enigmadan, a lazy match is not necessary here.

Comment: or you can simply use a roll-forth: `[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z]`

Comment: You were right in logic, and first one, I want to give you bounty!

Comment: Thanks @mahaidery, do you have any other questions about integrating it with MySQL (etc.) that I can expand my question with?

Answer (score 0):

The expression you are using searches for characters between 2 and unlimited times with these characters `ACDFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXZ`.

However, your RegEx expression is excluding `Y` (`UVWXZ])`)  therefore `Z` cannot be found since it is not surrounded by another character in your expression and the same principle applies to `B` (`[ACD`) also excluded in you RegEx expression. For example Z and A would match in an expression like `ZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA`

If those were **not** excluded on purpose probably better can be to use ranges like `[A-Z]`

Comment: Yes I want to exclude certain words in the match in my example: B and Y, the regex should exclude those and not count in the set!

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

Overall, MySQL regular expression support is pretty weak.

If you only need to match your capture group a minimum of two times, then you can simply use:

```
select *  from ... where ... regexp('([ACD].*){2,}') #could be `2,` or just `2`
```

If you ***need*** to match your capture group *more* than two times, then just change the number:

```
select *  from ... where ... regexp('([ACD].*){3}')
                                      #This number should match the number of matches you need
```

If you needed a minimum of 7 matches and you were using your previous capture group `[ACDF-KM-XZ]`

e.g.

```
select *  from ... where ... regexp('([ACDF-KM-XZ].*){7,}')
```

---

#### Response before edit:

Your regex is trying to find at least **two** characters from the set`[ACDFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXZ]`.

```
([ACDFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXZ]){2,}
```

The reason `A` and `Z` are not being matched in your example string (`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`) is because you are looking for two or more characters that are together that match your set. `A` is a single character followed by a character that does not match your set. Thus, A is not matched.

Similarly, `Z` is a single character preceded by a character that does not match your set. Thus, `Z` is not matched.

The bolded characters below do not match your set
A**B**CD**E**FGHIJK**L**MNOPQRSTUVWX**Y**Z

If you were to do a global search in the string, only the italicized characters would be matched:
A**B***CD***E***FGHIJK***L***MNOPQRSTUVWX***Y**Z

Comment: I want to match all in the set!

Comment: @mahaidery Well, therein lies your problem. Regex can only match consecutive characters. However, you can get a count of how many matches your regex has found in a specific string. This depends on the coding language that you are using though.

Comment: this is what my problem.. if I use [ACDFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXZ] it works perfectly, but I want it to only match when there letters in the set are 2 or more or repeated 2 or more times.. I will use this on mysql so no more string I would have..

Comment: @Sam That would be a whole lot simpler! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2 or more of a match on `[AKL]`, then you may use just `[AKL]` and may have `match >= 2`.

I am not good at SQL regex, but may be something like this?

```
check (dbo.RegexMatch( ['ABCVL'], '[AKL]' ) >= 2)
```

To put it in simple English, use `[AKL]` as your regex, and check the match on the string to be greater than 2.  Here's how I would do in Java:

```
private boolean search2orMore(String string) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[ACD]").matcher(string);
    int counter = 0;
    while (matcher.find())
    {
        counter++;
    }
    return (counter >= 2);
}
```

You can't use `[ACD]{2,}` because it always wants to match 2 or more of each characters and will fail if you have 2 or more matching single characters.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not very clear, but here is my trial pattern

```
\b(\S*[AKL]\S*[AKL]\S*)\b
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/11)

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure this should work in any case

```
(?<l>[^AKL\n]*[AKL]+[^AKL\n]*[AKL]+[^AKL\n]*)[\n\r]
```

replace AKL for letters you need can be done very easily dynamicly tell me if you need it

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
".*(.*[AKL].*){2,}.*" (without quotes)
```

It matches if there are at least two occurences of your charactes sorrounded by anything.
It is .NET regex, but should be same for anything else